# Peer to Peer Connection in Windows Store App (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, p2p

I'd like to know if anyone has managed to set up a peer-to-peer app for the Windows Store using HTML5 and JavaScript. Basically I want app client A to be able to connect and send data to app client B via a TCP or UDP socket (the problem I'm facing seems to be irrelevant to the socket type).

My main problem is that I am unsure how to obtain a suitable IP/port which the other client would be able to connect to. It seems like there would be issues with router firewalls and whatnot, but MS claims that peer-to-peer is possible.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I cannot use a third party service for communicating the data, because I want my app to be able to connect with other applications besides the one I'm writing. So something standard like TCP sockets is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/) for the desktop app development with web technology.

I don't know is TideSDK provide an API to access TCP or UDP communication, may be you could try read the [docs](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/). IMO best is you need to create a server to handle 1:1 connection between clients.

If you dont want to get mess with the server, you should get to know [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/how-pubnub-works) and [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: My problem isn't with not having access to the proper APIs for socket communication. My problem is not knowing how (if it is possible) to obtain the ip/port that my metro app would use for its socket listener so that external applications are able to make a connection to my listening app. The reason I can't use PubNub or something similar is because other applications (not mine) need to be able to connect as well. So something standard like a TCP socket is needed. I'll edit my question to reflect that as well.

Comment: @Ings I forgot to mention you in my comment